# Do I have to worry about useState causing a re-render?

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, block-editor

I'm creating a new block plugin, and I'm worried that it's `edit` function is being called too many times. I'm not sure this is the right terminology, as I'm new to JavaScript, React, etc..., but, it seems that `useState` causes a re-render. If I just have a really simple `edit`:

```
import { useState } from '@wordpress/element';

export default function MyEdit( props ) {
        const {
                attributes: {
                    anAttribute
                },
                setAttributes,
        } = props;

        const [ isValidating, setIsValidating ] = useState( false );
        const post_id = wp.data.select("core/editor").getCurrentPostId();
        console.log('Post ID is ', post_id);

        const MyPlaceholder = () => {
            return(
                <div>this is a test</div>
            );
        };

        const Component = MyPlaceholder;

        return <Component />;
}
```

then that `console.log` is getting hit twice per copy of the block on the post/page. I don't want to over-optimize things, but, equally, I don't know what this implies (is every script on the page getting re-executed twice?). Is this expected behavior for `useState`? Am I doing something wrong? Do I have to worry about it (from a speed perspective, from a potential race conditions as everything is re-rendered multiple times)?

Comment: `useState` is pretty much a wrapper around the react version so that core has API stability if React ever decided to change how that worked, their behaviour should be identical

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is expected behavior. If I add a similar `console.log` to native core blocks that use `useState`, I get the same effect. It seems that WordPress operates with `use strict`, and according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60840401/11020164), React double-invokes a number of things when in strict mode.

Comment: It should not matter how many times React invokes it, the result should always be the same. Your question implies you are unaware of `useEffect` and `useSelect` and encountering the problems they are designed to fix. You should expect to see the function called an arbitrary number of times, and if you've built your component correctly then it will be oblivious to this